# text-to-speech for arabic language

Tags: vb.net, text-to-speech, sapi

text-to-speech for English language using Visual Basic 2008

```
Dim speech speech = CreateObject("sapi.spvoice") 
speech.speak(TextBox1.Text)
```

My question, how this can be used for arabic languages  ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

From a [Microsoft support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306902):

"Microsoft does not provide additional speech engines (voices), but a number of third-party products are available that support the new Microsoft Speech API. For information on these products, visit the following Microsoft Web site: http://www.microsoft.com/speech/evaluation/thirdparty/engines.mspx"

Only problem is, that website seems to be down. If you do a search for third-party engines, you'll see a lot of links to that site, too. I'd try to hunt down if it still exists, or try to look for the specific third-party engine you'd need to support Arabic.

Comment: Hey mystery person, thanks for the downvote for... some reason.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no Arabic TTS SAPI available either from MS or third party softwares after searching for long time .
their many online services even few software that support Arabic TTS
Like [Acapela](http://nextup.com/acapela.html) which is working only with their software no third party support .
Anyway I think that will not support that much in your project . only if the case you need an Audio output for the text file , not to deal with it interactivity .
Edit==
I just found another software **Nuance Vocalizer Voice packs** you can found the package [here](http://visionaid.com/phpincludes/en/support/voices/voices.php) . and this is [the Official site](http://www.nuance.com/for-business/text-to-speech/vocalizer/index.htm) .according to the first source it Support SAPI .